# Invisible SurfaceView makes its parent black

Tags: android, surfaceview

I have a problem using a SurfaceView inside an activity layout. This is the piece of XML:

```
<LinearLayout...
    android:background="@drawable/background_image">
    ...
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/game_viewcontainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.85">

        <!-- SurfaceView will be placed here -->

     </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

As you can see, the SurfaceView (actually a subclass of it) is not directly placed into the XML, but I put it later from the code, this way:

1. In the activity's `onCreate()` I instantiate the SurfaceView, setting it to INVISIBLE. I don't want to show it now.
2. Few lines after I call `addView()` to place the surface inside `game_viewcontainer`
3. The activity is rendered.
4. After few seconds I switch the surface to VISIBLE.

The problem is that this sequence works on some testing devices with Android 4+, but it introduces an issue in Android 2.2: between the 2nd and 4th step the `game_viewcontainer` is **totally black** (it doesn't show `background_image`). Then, after setting the SurfaceView to VISIBLE, the problem disappears.

Why this behavior?